How to perform noisy simulation of qiskit fake backends?
I have qiskit fake backends present in qiskit ibm runtime, If I run the circuit directly on the backend is it noisy simulation, or should I use qiskit Aersimulator and then perform noisy simulation like shown in this blog : https://qiskit.github.io/qiskit-aer/tutorials/2_device_noise_simulation.html

Qiskit fake backends can be used directly for noisy simulations. For example:
from qiskit.circuit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit_ibm_runtime.fake_provider import FakeNairobiV2
from qiskit.visualization import plot_distribution

circ = QuantumCircuit(2)
circ.h(0)
circ.cx(0, 1)
circ.measure_all()

backend = FakeNairobiV2()
job = backend.run(circ)
plot_distribution(job.result().get_counts())

The result:


Great, how can I estimate how well a fake_backend is compatible with a circuit without executing it, any idea?

The fake backends in qiskit are built to mimic the behaviors of IBM Quantum systems using system snapshots. This system snapshots (or fake backends) contain important information about the quantum system, such as the coupling map, bases gates, qubit properties like T1 and T2, error rate, etc. So when you use a fake backend to run your circuit the noise model from the snapshot is automatically applied to your simulation. Which implies that when you run your circuits on fake backend that circui simulation is indeed a noisy simulation.
